# How to detect modified files and save in eclipse?

Tags: java, io, eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin which work with special json config files,and it can be runned by the Run button.
I make changes to the config without saving the file.
If I the hit the run button to try it out, plugin will use the config as it is on disk...
It would be nice if the tool would either save all files before running - 
or at least give a warning message that tells me that some files are not saved..

How can i detect modified files and get a list of this files?

How can i save changes in this files?

Comment: you modify your files in eclipse ? ... eclipse already displays a warning, no ?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at all the editors which are marked 'dirty' (have modified data) using something like:

```
IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();

IWorkbenchWindow[] windows = workbench.getWorkbenchWindows();

for (IWorkbenchWindow window : windows)
  {
    IWorkbenchPage[] pages = window.getPages();

    for (IWorkbenchPage page : pages)
      {
         IEditorPart[] editors = page.getDirtyEditors();

         for (IEditorPart editor : editors)
           {
             IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();

             if (input instanceof FileEditorInput)
              {
                IFile file = ((FileEditorInput)input).getFile();

                // TODO ... deal with file
              }
           }
      }
  }
```

Note: Not all editors use `FileEditorInput` so you might need more code if the editor is using a different input.

When you have an `IEditorPart` you can call the

```
public void doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor);
```

method to get the editor to save its data - but you should confirm with the user first that they want to do this.

Comment: A big thank you.
Another question
If i have a folders and each folder has a json files.
I edited file.
I need to find a path to the folder where this file saved.
then find all files in this folder and check if it modified .
then save all modified files from this folder.

Comment: If you have a new problem you should ask a new question. Also consider accepting existing answers (click the tick mark next to the answer).